# Close app window, but not kill driver session

Tags: c#, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I find strange behavior in my auto-test, I use "WindowsDriver" and after the test finishes I need to close the app, no selenium methods work. My desktop app closes only if I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>. But after this action my session does not die and I don't use key action correct for normalize I need call "task manager".

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide what type of object did you use for session?

Comment: post actual code, not images of code

Comment: I use WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session; Sorry cannot post all code(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do ALT+F4. 
session.Quit() will close the browser and kill session as well.

So, the second part of your code should be enough without ALT+F4 code:

```
    if (session != null)
    {
        session.Quit();
        session= null;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately in not work, but I already find good solutions. foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if(HapticAppId.Contains(process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory + "\\" + process.ProcessName))
                {
                    process.Kill();
                    return;
                }
            }